# If $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite positive measure, there is a finite measure $\lambda$ such that $\mu\ll\lambda$ and $\lambda\ll\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(X,\mathscr{M})$ be a measurable space. If $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite positive measure on $\mathscr{M}$, there is a finite measure $\lambda$ on $\mathscr{M}$ such that $\mu\ll\lambda, \lambda\ll\mu$.

I think I can use the following theorem:

> If $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite positive measure on $\mathscr{M}$,$\exists w\in L^1(\mu)$ such that $0<w(x)<1$ for all $x\in X$.

I let $d\lambda=wd\mu$. Then the first absolute continuity is obvious since:
$$\int_E d\lambda=\int_E wd\mu\leq\int_E d\mu=0$$

But how do we know the second absolute continuity holds?
If $E$ is compact, we can find the minimum value $w$ takes on $E$, say, $m$ and the desired result follows from $0=\frac{1}{m}\int_E wd\mu\geq\int_E d\mu$.
Can we do similar thing when $E$ is not compact? Or do we have to take a different approach?

I would appreciate any comment or suggestion. Thank you for reading.

Comment: You are on the right track. You defined $\lambda(E)=\int_E wd\mu$.  Then it is imediate that $\lambda <<\mu$.  To prove that $\mu<<\lambda$, suppose $\lambda(E)=0$. Then $ \int_E wd\mu=0$. Then for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ $n>0$, $$0\leq \tfrac{1}{n}\mu(\{x \in E : w(x)>\tfrac{1}{n}\})\leq \int_E wd\mu=0$$
So $\mu(\{x \in E : w(x)>\tfrac{1}{n}\})=0$. Since $0<w(x)$ for all $x\in X$, we have that
$$E=\bigcup_{n>0} \{x \in E : w(x)>\tfrac{1}{n}\}$$
So $\mu(E)=0$. So $\mu<<\lambda$.

Comment: @Ramiro Thank you so much for your clear explanation.

Comment: Even if $E$ is compact, $w$ does not have to be continuous, so minimum may not be attainable there. Anyways, in this kind of problems you don't need any topology, so try to think in measure-theoretic terms: sets of positive measure etc.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, note that since $w\in L^1(\mu)$, we have $\lambda(X)=\int_X wd\mu<\infty$, so $\lambda$ is finite.